# hbase - how to change tables structure without drop tables

Tags: grails, groovy, nosql, hadoop, hbase

i use grails-1.3.2 and [gorm-hbase-0.2.4](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gorm-hbase) plugin.

Sometimes i need to change tables structure(add new tables or columns).
I have created Car table:

```
class Car{
    static belongsTo = [user:User]

    String color
    String model
    //.....

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

but when i want to create car object:

```
def create = {
        Car car = new Car()
        car.properties = params
        car.save(flush: true)        
 }
```

I got the following exception:

```
ERROR gorm.SavePersistentMethod  - APP_CAR
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: APP_CAR
```

After i run application with create-drop, everithing starts work good..
but i can not after every changes delete all data,
i thought plugin have to  do all updates

so, i am looking some way after changind tables structure continue to run application without drop tables..

If anybody know solution please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails will NOT do automatic updates to your tables, what if it drops a column in production automatically? Maybe that is not what you wanted.

There is a database migration plugin to do this and here is an excellent [link](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/08/database-migration-in-grails.html) that explains it. Note that you need to use grails **prod**  instead of using the ones directly in the link, otherwise it will run in development mode only. The link does not show prod in its commands.

The official links are [here](http://www.grails.org/plugin/database-migration) and the spring source blog about this is [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/17/countdown-to-grails-2-0-database-migrations/).

Answer (score 0):

database migration plugin will not be works, because it works only with hibernate.
You need to do some changes in plugin source. HBasePluginSupport.grovy

```
static doWithApplicationContext = {ApplicationContext applicationContext ->
    LOG.debug("Closure HBasePluginSupport.doWithApplicationContext{} invoked with arg $applicationContext")

    assert !PluginManagerHolder.getPluginManager().hasGrailsPlugin("hibernate"),"hibernate plug-in conflicts with gorm-hbase plug-in"

    // Read data source configuration, setting defaults as required
    def dataSource = application.config.dataSource
    // TODO write tests for this <--- Even maybe figure out if this is ever invoked
    if (!dataSource) dataSource = new HBaseDefaults()

    def dbCreate = dataSource?.dbCreate
    if (!dbCreate) dbCreate = "create-drop"
    LOG.debug("Data Source configured with dbCreate set to $dbCreate")

    // TODO Complete dbCreate related processing
    if (dbCreate?.toUpperCase()?.equals("CREATE-DROP")) {
        def createIndexedTables = dataSource?.indexed
        LOG.debug ("Flag createIndexedTables set to $createIndexedTables")
        def tableManager = HBaseLookupUtils.getBean("hbase.table.manager")

        tableManager.createSequenceTable()
        tableManager.createReferenceTable()

        application.domainClasses.each {domainClass ->
            LOG.debug("Adding table for Domain Class $domainClass")
            tableManager.createDomainTable(domainClass, createIndexedTables)
        }

        LOG.debug("List of all store found :")
        tableManager.getTableNames().each {tn ->
            LOG.debug("- $tn")
        }
    } else if (dbCreate?.toUpperCase()?.equals("UPDATE")) {
        def createIndexedTables = dataSource?.indexed
        def tableManager = HBaseLookupUtils.getBean("hbase.table.manager")
        def existingTables = tableManager.getTableNames();

        application.domainClasses.each {domainClass ->
            LOG.debug("Domain Class $domainClass")
            def tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(HBaseNameUtils.getDomainTableName(domainClass))
            if (!existingTables.contains(tableDesc.getNameAsString())) {
                tableManager.createDomainTable(domainClass, createIndexedTables)
                LOG.debug("Adding table for Domain Class $domainClass")
            }
        }
    }

    application.domainClasses.each {domainClass ->
        LOG.debug("Adding dbms related methods to Domain Class $domainClass")
        def domainClassManager = new HBaseDomainClassManager()
        domainClassManager.createQueryMethods(domainClass)
        domainClassManager.createPersistenceMethods(domainClass)
        domainClassManager.addLazyLoadingSupport(domainClass)
        domainClassManager.addDynamicFinders(domainClass)
    }
}
```